# Check status of Update / Insert Query in MySQL stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I need to check if

- An UPDATE statement executed successfully or not.
- How many rows were updated by UPDATE statement.
- An INSERT statement executed successfully or not.
- How many rows were updated by INSERT statement.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
dbOperation(IN param1 varchar(10), OUT status INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT ///
    //check insert status. 
    SET status=// 0 or 1 based on check. 
    IF status=1 THEN
       UPDATE ///
       //check update status. 
       SET status=// 0 or 1 based on check. 
    ELSE 
        status=0;      
END
```

`status=1` when statements execute successfully.
`status=0` when statements fail to execute successfully.

Comment: If a query fails for whatever reason MySQL will raise an error, which you can get via the API you are using to connect. You can use [ROW_COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) to see how many rows were updated in the last query.

Comment: Thanks. Please move this to answer. I will accept. A small code snippet will help more. :)